# Issues in image uploading using vue-wysiwyg

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am using **[vue-wysiwyg editor](https://github.com/chmln/vue-wysiwyg)** in my laravel-vue application. In this editor there is an option to upload images and through incomplete documentation of this package I am able to upload the image and get public url of the uploaded file. But this package works sometimes and does not work at all sometimes.

Here is how I am using this package

**main.js**

```
import wysiwyg from "vue-wysiwyg";

Vue.use(wysiwyg, {
    forcePlainTextOnPaste: true,
    image: {
        uploadURL: "/api/save-support-files",
        dropzoneOptions: {}
    },
});
```

**/api/save-support-files**

```
public function uploadUserFile(Request $request)
    {
        $uploadedFile = $request->file('file');


        if (false == $uploadedFile) {
            return response()->api(false, 'Kindly upload a file');
        }

        $allowed_file_extentions = [
            'jpeg',
            'png',
            'jpg',
            'gif',
            'svg'
        ];

        if (false == in_array($uploadedFile->getClientOriginalExtension(), $allowed_file_extentions)) {
            return response()->api(false,'Allowed file types are jpeg, png, jpg, gif, svg',null);
        }


        $file_url = Storage::disk('public')->putFileAs('/support-files',$uploadedFile,generateRandomString('5').'.'.$uploadedFile->getClientOriginalExtension());

//        return response()->api(true,'File uploaded successfully',config('app.url').'/storage/'.$file_url);

        return config('app.url').'/storage/'.$file_url;
}
```

Issues I am facing right now:

1. As soon as I select image from file browser, image is uploaded through api successfully but it is not showing in editor.
2. Unable to select already uploaded image, I have to refresh the page and then again select file to upload it again.

Is anyone having solution to this problem ? Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0):

my upload store function look like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate(['file' => 'required']);

    $file = $request->file('file');
    if ($file->isValid()) {
        $path = $file->storePublicly(now()->format('Y' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'm' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'd'));

        return response(Storage::disk('public')->url($path), Response::HTTP_CREATED)->withHeaders(
            [
                'content-type' => 'text/html'
            ]
        );
    }

    abort(Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

make sure you have set `APP_URL` in `.env` to full url (http://my-site.com)

make sure you run `php artisan storage:link`